How to return different columns from the same table based on Oracle database version? (banner vs banner_full in v$version)
I need to return the BANNER_FULL column from v$version if the database version is 18+, otherwise return the BANNER column.  Both exist in all versions, but banner is deprecated.
column v_dbversion new_value v_dbversion

select to_number(substr(version,1,2)) v_dbversion
  from product_component_version
 where upper(product) like '%DATABASE%';

select case
       when &v_dbversion < 18 then
         banner
       when &v_dbversion >= 18 then
         banner_full
       end as "Database Version"
  from v$version;


V_DBVERSION
-----------
12
banner_full
*
ERROR at line 5
ORA-00904: "BANNER_FULL": invalid identifier

If I comment out the "when >=18 then banner_full" lines it works on ver 12 and visa versa with ver 19.

you can't mix select with the case when, you will need dynamic sql for that

I'm not convinced that your v$version includes a banner_full column.

Use PL/SQL and implement conditional logic based on the dictionary.

Still returns ORA-000904 when banner_full is referenced.  Even though it's not in the if/then/else/end if branch.

You can create a function and use conditional compilation:
CREATE FUNCTION db_banner
RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
IS
  v_version VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  SELECT $IF DBMS_DB_VERSION.VERSION < 18
         $THEN banner
         $ELSE banner_full
         $END
  INTO   v_version
  FROM   v$version
  WHERE  ROWNUM = 1;

  RETURN v_version;
END;
/

Then in Oracle 11 the output of:
SELECT db_banner()
FROM   dual

is:



DB_BANNER()




Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production



Oracle 11g fiddle
And in Oracle 18, the output is:



DB_BANNER()




Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - ProductionVersion 18.4.0.0.0



Oracle 18 fiddle

If you want a view, rather than a function, then you can run this once on each of the databases:
BEGIN
  IF DBMS_DB_VERSION.VERSION < 18 THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE VIEW banner (banner) AS SELECT banner FROM v$version';
  ELSE
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE VIEW banner (banner) AS SELECT banner_full FROM v$version';
  END IF;
END;
/

Then you can use:
SELECT banner FROM banner;

Which outputs:



BANNER




Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production


PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production


CORE  11.2.0.2.0  Production


TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production


NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production



fiddle
or:



BANNER




Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - ProductionVersion 18.4.0.0.0



fiddle

That worked.  I'd rather not create a function though.  Is there anyway to do this without creating an object?

@GlyphMaster Added an option for creating a view instead of a function.

MT0's answer is good answer. but another solution is using dynamic SQL as follows:
CREATE FUNCTION db_banner RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    v_version   VARCHAR2(255);
    v_sql1      VARCHAR2(100);
    v_sql2      VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    v_sql1 := 'SELECT banner_full FROM v$version WHERE  ROWNUM = 1';
    v_sql2 := 'SELECT banner FROM v$version WHERE  ROWNUM = 1';
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql1 INTO v_version;
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql2 INTO v_version;
    END ;

  RETURN v_version;
END;


Can we guarantee the Database version will always be the first row returned?  Any way to do this without creating an object?  It's a healthcheck and it runs on thousands of databases.
